# Java How do I write a resource (internal text file) out to a directory?

Tags: java, filewriter

I have a file I'm storing within my jar that I use a default setting file. I wish to write this file out to a user defined path. How do I write it out? This file that I'm trying to write out is in the same location as my class files that will be writing this file

Comment: I am not sure if you can write to the class file location if the class is packaged within the jar.

Comment: *"default setting file"*  Attribute+value pairs are well stored as [`Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html).  What form are these preferences in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `getResourceAsStream` to access the resource. Create a `FileOutputStream` for the file you wish to write. Read from one stream and write to the other. Preferably, use buffering, and don't forget to close your streams when you're done.

See [Location-Independent Access to Resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html).

Answer (score 2):

use "getResourceAsStream"

-> http://mindprod.com/jgloss/getresourceasstream.html

Answer (score 1):

given a `resource` that you want to write to a given `Path path`, then you can use:

```
try(InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(resource)){
    Files.copy(is, path);
} catch (Exception e){
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```